# How does a 3D printer print itself given the huge size?

Tags: desktop-printer, replicating-printers

How can this be done given that the object to be printed is the same size as itself? In the CubePro printers that I have used before, the object to be printed is inside some kind of glass panel. Only objects that are smaller can be printed.

Comment: This question is based on an assumption, namely that 3D printers can print themselves in one piece. Maybe you could edit this question to add some basis for this assumption?

Comment: This question doesn't show much sign of any research. I'm struggling to see how it can be improved to be honest.

Answer (score 4):

3D printers obviously do not print themselves. 3D printers are sometimes used to make *parts for* other 3D printers, and this is what is meant by "self-replicating" 3D printers (which is a bit of a misnomer, considering that all designs require a substantial amount of non-printed "vitamin" parts).

A printer that is able to produce many of its own parts is the [RepRap snappy](http://reprap.org/wiki/Snappy), which (as the name suggests) consists of plastic parts that - while they each fit within the build volume - snap together to make up the larger parts for the printer.

[image: RepRap Snappy, from the RepRap wiki, GNU Free Documentation License 1.2]

Comment: So, replicating printers mean they print components of a 3D printer but assembly of these components is still a separate process?